# How common are "arrove" and "arriven" (vs. "arrived")?

Tags: past-tense, past-participles, conjugation, irregular, strong-verbs

So to start things off, I know that the proper past tense of the word *arrive* would be the word *arrived*.

And that sounds fine for me if you are singularly referring to yourself, such as:

> I have arrived at my home.

But when I try to use the word to refer to a group of people, such as:

> We have arrived at our home.

It just peeves me for some reason. It feels more natural to say:

> We arrove at our home.

Or even:

> We have arriven at our home.

They both feel far more natural to me than *arrived* does for some reason.
Wiktionary lists *[arrove](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arrove)* as a non-standard alternative to *arrived,* which indicates that at least some other people have felt the same way. How frequently are *arrove* or *arriven* used? What region(s) does this dialect belong to?

Me from the future: To anyone interested, I have discovered that Google Docs recognizes 'arriven' as a word but not 'arrove'

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?  That's a good first step.

Comment: @fixer1234 yes I did a bit of digging and didn't find a single occurrence of the words `arrove` and `arriven`. But I didn't exclude the possibility that they are rather archaic or belong to a specific dialect and therefore they didn't turn up in my searches.

Comment: "have arrove" seems doubly strange to me because I can't even think of a verb that ends in "ive" in the plain form and "ove" in the past participle. Maybe "dive" for some people? Anyway, "arrove" or "arriven" are just analogical re-formations. I think any educated speaker would agree that they are non-standard, but nobody is in a unique position to say they are "valid" or "invalid." So I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @sumelic it isn't that the question is opinion based, I merely used the wrong word. Rather than questioning the validity of the words I actually meant to ask about the frequency of usage (if at all).

Comment: @sumelic and yes, it primarily because of words like `dove` exist that `arrove` sounds natural to me, so more than likely it is an issue of dialect.

Comment: Try Google Ngram.

Comment: @Xanne Well that's neat! I never knew such a thing existed, sadly either the terms `arrove` and `arriven` never made an appearance in books or the words truly are never spoken.

Comment: @Xanne I stand corrected, I was doing a comparison between arrived, arrove, and arriven and due to arrived being so vastly more common the other two effectively became negligible, well consider this question closed.

Comment: As sumelic indirectly said, you’re conflating _past tense_ and _past participle_. The past tense is “we arrived [drove]”; the past participle is used to form the perfect tense “we have arrived [driven]”. It sounds like you speak a dialect where the two are not usually distinguished in strong verbs, since you seem to find “we have arrove” more natural than “we have arriven”. I suspect that even if this is the case, you would not say “I have was” but “I have been”. (Also note that Google Ngrams is a search corpus for _published books_ and says nothing at all about speech.)

Comment: @sumelic “Have arrove” seems about one-and-a-halfly strange to me for the same reason, but there are a fair few lects, especially in AmE, where past tense and past participle have generally coalesced in most strong verbs too. I’ve heard plenty of people say “I have gave” or “I have went” or “I have tore”, so while “I have arrove” has two odd things about it, one of them is at least recognisable as adhering to a pattern (and the other as trying to find a pattern to adhere to).

Comment: I don't know if the existence of the Google Ngram viewer means this question should be considered closed. It is a useful tool, but maybe you could edit the question to also ask about the geographical distribution of these forms. As far as I know, the Ngram Viewer can only show differences between US and British usage in its corpora; it can't show any more finely grained regional differences or, as Janus Bahs Jacquet said, spoken frequency.

Comment: @SemperAmbroscus I don’t think so. _Be_ is, as far as I know, not part of this merger anywhere. I don’t recall hearing anyone say “I have did”, either, but I may have.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: "Be" and "done" are I believe often leveled in favor of the past-participle form: "I been" and "I done it." There may be specialized meanings to the use of past-participle or preterite form for the finite past tense (e.g. I think "I been" contrasts with "I was" in (some forms of?) AAVE, and I think I've heard of a lexical verb/auxiliary contrast between "I done" and "I did": even people who say "I done it" will say "Did you do it?").

Comment: @sumelic That’s true, but I think that’s a different levelling. _Go_ is frequently levelled either way (“I have went” ~ “I gone”), and instinctively to me those two _feel_ like they belong to different types of speech. I may be mistaken there, though.

Comment: The Ngram for arrove and arriven shows much more common use pre-1900, then a sharp drop-off, with arrove far more common than arriven.  "We arrove" is beginning to sound natural to me.  I agree it's only one tool; but you can look at the specific texts.

Comment: I have heard of "arriven" ... a high-school classmate of mine told me that it felt right to him, but he now knew it was wrong, so no longer used it.

Comment: On Ngram sources: turns out "arrove" is also a weight measure.  Also that it's used as the past participle; "has arrove", "is arrove."

Comment: If you have to ask, you shouldn't use either.  Really, even if you don't have to ask, you shouldn't use either unless you're writing some arcane poetry and really need them for a rhyme.

Comment: Your problem is that English as a language is very irregular, mainly because it's an agglutination of multiple different languages with different rules.  As someone with a young child, I regularly correct "goed" to "went", "gived" to "gave", "throwed" to "threw", and so on.  Unfortunately if you want to communicate with another English speaker then you need to speak English.  In your favour is that English has many dialects, so English speakers are relatively insensitive to grammatical flaws, but you cannot expect to invent your own personal dialect and have it readily understood. :)

Comment: You're just expecting 'arrive' to work like the much more common 'drive', an easy (non-standard) alternative to make.

Comment: @Graham I think you're missing that the asker here is actually a native speaker of English—and that every single person on the planet essentially has their own personal dialect (it's called their idiolect) and are generally quite readily understood. The problem here is the reverse your child’s: children in general use as regular forms as possible because systems tend to come before individual irregularities; here the asker is using an irregular form instead of a regular one. (I also feel like _agglomeration_ would be a better word than _agglutination_ here, but that may just be me.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You're right that I'm missing that, because it didn't seem to me that this was something a native speaker would ask.  Of course we have our own personal dialect as a combination of dialects we've been exposed to, but the question asks about a structure which is not part of any regular English dialect the asker has personally heard.  That makes it curious that they'd latch onto irregular forms (albeit ones which do recur) as the "regular" form.

Comment: @Graham Not so very curious—that's how _dove_ as the past tense of _dive_ arose, and that eventually made its way into many English dialects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Historical

According to [OED](http://oed.com), these forms *did* exist (not necessarily with your spelling), as it mentions in its entry for *arrive* (v):

> In 14–15th cent. occas. aphetized to rive; and inflected after strong verbs, with past tense *arove* (*rove*, *arofe*), past participle *ariven* (*aryven*).

This is historical (so I'm not sure why Wiktionary lists *arrove*).

---

OED gives this example:

> His nauye greate..In Thamis **aroue**.
>   <sub>1470   J. Hardyng Chron. xlii</sub>

The [Middle English Dictionary](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED2253&egs=all&egdisplay=open) gives other examples:

> Ascalus & Alacus auntrid to lond, And **aryuen** full rad with þere rank shippes.
>   <sub>c1540(?a1400) Destr.Troy (Htrn 388)   5792</sub>

> But he ne koude **arryuen** in no coost Where as he myghte fynde..Two creatures acordyng in feere.
>   <sub>(c1395) Chaucer CT.WB.(Manly-Rickert)</sub>

The 1830 [Book of Mormon](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Book_of_Mormon_(1830)) uses "arriven" at least four times, e.g:

> And again: They were wroth with him, when they had **arriven** to the promised land, because they said that he had taken the ruling of the people out of their hands; and they sought to kill him.

---

### Dialects

**"Up-State New York"**:

> Arrove for arrived appears to be an analogous form based on some
>    word like dive-dove.
>   <sub>[The Dialect of Up-State New York: A Study of the Folk-Speech in Two Works of Marietta Holley](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4172728?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)</sub>

**Smokey Mountain English**:

> Irregular verbs may be treated as regular verbs and vice
>   versa, or they may be treated as irregular in a different way from more general dialects (arrove, blowed, costed).
>   <sub>[American English](http://venec.ulstu.ru/lib/disk/2011/Warafutdinova1.pdf#page=23)</sub>

Comment: +1, but neither of your two MED citations is a past participle: the first is a plural simple past and the second is an infinitive. The reduction to *rive* is significant: *rove* and *riven* are the past and past participle of *rive*, so there's extra pressure for analogical regularization there.

Comment: I thought "arrove" sounded normal.  I grew up in up-state New York.  :-)

Answer (score 9):

Historical Linguistics: An Introduction by Lyle Campbell (MIT Press, 2013) (originally published in 1988) suggests these forms are developing or are naturally generated:

> **Analogical extension** (somewhat rarer than analogical levelling)
> extends the already existing alternation of some pattern to new forms
> which did not formerly undergo the alternation. An example of
> analogical extension is seen in the case mentioned above of dived
> being replaced by dove on analogy with the 'strong' verb pattern as in
> drive/drove, ride/rode and so on, an extension of the alternating
> pattern of the strong verbs. Other examples follow.
>
> (I) Modern English
> wear/wore, which is now in the strong verb pattern, was historically a
> weak verb which changed by extension of the strong verb pattern, as
> seen in earlier English werede ' wore', which would have become modem
> weared if it had survived.
>
> (2) Other examples in English include the
> development of the nonstandard past tense forms which show extension
> to the strong verb pattern which creates alternations that formerly
> were not there, as in: **arrive/arrove** (Standard English
> arrive/arrived), and squeeze/squoze (Standard squeeze/squeezed).

Comment: Certainly where I live (Northern England), 'Squoze' is in fairly common usage, although I suspect this is more of a cute colloquialism, rather than realising it might actually be correct.

Answer (score 3):

They used to be more popular than they are now (but "arrived" has always been at least 100x as common).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the graph--how did you get it copied/posted?

Comment: I copied it pixel by pixel.  (PrtSc + Paint + a lot of cursing)

Comment: Save to file, then use the file in your answer.

Comment: I'm looking at the ngrams and "arrived" isn't just 100x more popular, it's closer to 100,000x for most of the duration, and the closest I see is 1870, where it's almost 10,000x. Both of the "alternates" are a rounding error at best.

Comment: @Kevin - Yeah, I didn't try to work it out, but when I added "arrived" to the chart the other words tuned into flat lines on the bottom axis.  But the words are common enough to not be simply OCR errors and the like.

Answer (score 3):

Raised in Wisconsin, I use "arrove" and "arriven", regularly.  I think probably by analogy with dive/dove, drive/drove, ride/rode, but, regardless, "arrived" sounds unnatural, especially for the simple past/preterite...

Comment: From the U.S. east coast, I believe that the past tense of “dive” is “dived”.  [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/dive) and [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dive) concur; [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dive) and the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=dive) list both “dived” and “dove” — but they both list “dived” first.  What do you use for the past tense of “connive”, “contrive”, “derive”, “scrive” and “strive” (and “highfive” & “jive”)?

Answer (score 0):

In a diary entry from 1980, when I was 17, admittedly writing only for myself and being deliberately archaic, I wrote, "The big day hath arriven, and beginneth like unto a fizzle."  Context:  long-planned outing, unexpected change of plans.  My family is from north-central Ohio, and I do say "worsh", "crick", and "red up the table", and say "thuh" before consonants and "thee" before vowels.  I can't say I ever heard anyone say "arrove" or "arriven".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This personal anecdote does not really answer the question.  When you emphasize that n=1 in your personal writing, it's more of a comment. 1980 was not seeing common usage like this. 
 Please see the helpful [help] and take the site [tour].